# SpringAMQP Queue creation with args

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I created an queue with message expiration args but  i get the following error while starting up the server.

```
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.c.RabbitAdmin [RabbitAdmin.java:375] Auto-declaring a non-durable Queue (TEST_QUEUE). It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.
pool-1-thread-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory [CachingConnectionFactory.java:249] Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'durable' for queue 'EXP_MSG' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true', class-id=50, method-id=10)
ERROR [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:914] Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:63) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitAccessor.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitAccessor.java:110) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

I use Spring boot 1.2.8 and Spring  4.2.5 version.

```
   @Bean
    Queue expiredMessageQueue() {
        Map args = new HashMap();
        args.put("x-message-ttl", 60000);
        return new Queue(expiredMessageQueue, false, false, false,args);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> inequivalent arg 'durable' for queue 'EXP_MSG' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true'

That means that there is already present such a queue on RabbitMQ Broker, but with  different properties.

If you would like to change it and have recreated via application, you should remove it first from Broker before start application. Or align all options with an existing one.

That is called like `passiveDeclaration`. The listener exactly needs a real queue to subscribe, and there is only why way to check if it exist with desired state, try to declare it during listener start.